# É possível adicionar um número diferente para cada <li> criada num for?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um carossel em `bootstrap` e para chamar os posts do wordpress dentro dele, tenho um `for` dentro da `<div class="carousel-inner">`.

O `for` consegue criar os posts, porém não estou conseguindo incluir os indicadores de cada post (as bolinhas que ficam abaixo do carrossel ou `<ol class="carousel-indicators">`).

A estrutura dos indicadores é:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#id_carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
</ol>
```

O que eu preciso é desse `data-slide-to`, pois ele está sendo definido como 0 para cada post que foi criado, ou seja, independente de qual eu clique, o carrossel volta pro primeiro post.

O que eu tenho:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= NUMBER_OF_SLIDES; $i++) : ?>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="<?php echo ($i == 1) ? 'active' : ''; ?>"></li>
   <?php endfor; ?>
</ol>
```

As `<li>` são criadas dentro do `for`, porém não estou conseguindo atribuir um número diferente do `data-slide-to` para cada `<li>` criada.

O que estou tentando fazer, é com que o output desse `for` saia dessa maneira:

```
<li data-slide-to="0">
<li data-slide-to="1">
<li data-slide-to="2">
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seria isso?

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= NUMBER_OF_SLIDES; $i++) : ?>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="<?php echo ($i == 1) ? 'active' : ''; ?>"></li>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Eu tentei esse método anteriormente, mas o problema é que ao clicar em qualquer bullet, ele pula um slide ou não vai, mesmo estando de 1 a 5 corretamente. Será pelo fato de não estar iniciando em 0?

Comment: Bem, era isso mesmo, a falta de iniciar em 0 hahahahaha quebrei a cabeça nisso atoa, mas obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: sim, provavelmente. Por isso iniciei o $i em 0. Acho que deve ser isso mesmo.

Comment: blz isso ae, show! =)